# tqdm gives No module named 'tqdm' after installing it

Tags: python, pip, tqdm

So I'm working on a basic airdrop software, I want to use tqdm to show when the file is uploading but the problem is that I have tqdm install

```
pip install tqdm
```

but it give me this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tqdm'
```

Here is a picture of how I'm dealing with this problem
[image]

Also when I type

```
pip list
```

it appears, but it doesn't work

[image]

any idea of what's wrong in here?

Comment: Looks like you have both python 3.8 and 3.9 installed, and pip is installing the package only for python 3.8 (notice the directory tqdm is installed to), but your py command starts python 3.9. I suggets using something like pyenv to isolate your python versions. You can also run pip as a module: `py -m pip install tqdm`

Comment: oh, that's right, I didn't see that is was installing on python 3.8, thank you so much!